# Strange padding in ios14

Tags: css, padding, ios14

As can be seen from the below picture, we can find a `white padding` in the middle of `gray background` and `blue border`. It is STRANGE because the padding is not set by code or style, and it just happend in ios14+ version.

box css style:

```css
.box{
    position: fixed;
    left: 16px;
    right: 16px;
    bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background: $colorWhite;
    box-shadow: 0px 14px 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0px 2px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you put up a snippet which shows the problem as just using your given CSS (and altering the width of the blue border) I don't see any gap (using IOS14.2 Safari on iPad).

Comment: what snippet do i omission?

Comment: This [link]https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do has information on how to create a Stackoverflow snippet - it's code within your question but in a form that can be run and that shows your problem.

Comment: It is normal in html, css. I think it is not the problem with css but Taro library, thank you!!!